# Stop decreasing number with built in condition React/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering

I have a button that should decrease a number. How can I create a condition that stops decreasing when my number is 1 in React?

```js
<Button type="button" size="small" onClick={() => 
            handleUpdateCartQty(item.id, item.quantity - 1)}>-</Button>
```

something like that:

```js
if(item.quantity == 1){
<Button type="button" size="small" onClick={() => 
            handleUpdateCartQty(item.id, item.quantity)}>-</Button>
}else{
<Button type="button" size="small" onClick={() => 
            handleUpdateCartQty(item.id, item.quantity - 1)}>-</Button>
}
```

**Note**

`item.quantity` holds the value of the number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) for this purpose

```
<Button type="button" size="small" onClick={() => 
            handleUpdateCartQty(item.id,  Math.max(0, item.quantity - 1)}>-</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use the ternary operator as the `handleUpdateCartQty` parameter, e.g:

```js
<Button type="button" size="small" onClick={() => 
            handleUpdateCartQty(item.id, item.quantity <= 1 ? item.quantity : item.quantity - 1)}>-</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to point out  that it is not always a good practice to use `onclick`.
I would suggest you to try use `addEventListener` instead.

Check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (item.quantity > 1) {
    handleUpdateCartQty(item.id, item.quantity)
    item.quantity--;
  }
})
```

```html
<button type="button" size="small" >-</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways of achieving this

Let me share 2 ways with you so that you can select one as per your requirements

If a button decrements the count then there may be another way to increment the count

If thats the case then you can disable the decrement count button as soon as your value is 1
`disabled={newValue<=1}`

The alternative is to add an `if` condition inside your function

```
const handleUpdateCartQty = (id, newVal) => {
     if(newVal < 1) {
       // showNotification('min allowed quantity is 1');
       return;
     } 
    // Do update operation  
 }
```

If you are not disabling the button and not displaying any notification that `min quantity should be 1` while just handling condition inside your code then, It may give an impression to the user that button is not working